# What were those two military helicopters that I recorded?

Tags: military, helicopter, aircraft-identification

I have recently recorded two military helicopters. Here is a screenshot of it:
[image]

Comment: Geo location will help because military models have relatively predictable area of operation.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell from such a low resolution picture. Due to the shape of the narrow body, they look like USMC Bell AH-1 SuperCobra. It is probably the AH-1Z Viper version based on the four blade rotor.